# Maximum value on JTextField

Tags: java, swing, limit, jtextfield

I want to have a `JTextField` in which you can only type numbers (integers and decimals), and you can only type numbers below 12345 and above 0. How would I do this? What I have right now:

```
    JTextField tf = new JTextField();

    final PlainDocument doc = new PlainDocument();
    doc.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {

        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            String s = doc.getText(0, offset) + string + doc.getText(offset, doc.getLength() - offset);
            try {
                if (Double.parseDouble(s) > 12345) {
                    fb.replace(0, 5, "12345", attr);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                fb.insertString(offset, string.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            String s = (doc.getText(0, offset) + text + doc.getText(offset, doc.getLength() - offset)).trim();
            try {
                if (Double.parseDouble(s) > 12345) {
                    fb.replace(0, 5, "12345", attrs);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                fb.insertString(offset, text.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attrs);
            }
        }

    });

    tf.setDocument(doc);
```

(This is then added to a `JFrame` window at `BorderLayout.CENTER`, with nothing else in it)

But it doesn't work (I can't type anything). What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** I would prefer to use something along the lines of the above approach (Using `Document`s) and not have to resort to something like `JFomattedTextField`, if possible.

Comment: Consider using a `JSpinner` with a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it doesn't work (I can't type anything).

```
if (Double.parseDouble(s) > 12345) {
    fb.replace(0, 5, "12345", attrs);
}
```

If the value is > 12345 you update the document with a hardcoded value.

But, if the value is < 12345 you don't do anything. You need to insert the typed character in the document, by invoking `super.replace(...)` or `super.insertString()`.